# WPF databinding to instances of an object in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

For databinding as an example I use two ways for filling a listbox : one in code-behind and one in Xaml.

In code-behind it is fairly easy to bind the listbox to an instance of object (in this example an observable collection 'basicUsers').
In Xaml I don't succeed in binding to an instance. It seems only possible to bind to an object (custom class based on observable collection). Can the data in instances of this object be used as datasource in XAML?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <src:CustomTypeUsers  x:Key="myDataSource"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="lbUsers" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="10,10,70,141" Width="212"></ListBox>
    <ListBox Name="lbUsers2" ItemsSource="{StaticResource myDataSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="10,149,70,0" />
</Grid>
```

code-behind :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
       private ObservableCollection<User> basicUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>(); 
       private CustomTypeUsers customUsers = new CustomTypeUsers(); 
       public Window1()
       {
          InitializeComponent();

          basicUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe" });
          basicUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe" });

          customUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "Natasha Doe" });
          customUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "Angelina Doe" });

          lbUsers.ItemsSource = basicUsers;
       }

       private void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
         basicUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "New user" });
       }
    }

    public class User
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomTypeUsers : ObservableCollection<User>
    {
        public CustomTypeUsers()
        {
            Add(new User() { Name = "Emma Doe" });
            Add(new User() { Name = "Betty Doe" });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually using a Binding. Try `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}}"` instead.

Comment: That did the same thing : I would like to see "Natasha Doe" in Listbox lbUsers2 (without using code behind: not:  lbUsers2.ItemsSource = customUsers;)

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of searching, I found a solution for my question (left it here for others with similar startup issues):
-First : set the binding **source** to the surrounding **object** (in this example : the object is MainWindow => DataContext = this;)
-Second : to make binding to your variables possible, make **properties** of them.
-Third : if you want to acces deeper lying variables, also make properties of them and access them in XAML almost the way you would do in c# : for example : User.[1].Name.

In code :

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<User>  basicUsers { get; private set; }
    public CustomTypeUsers customUsers { get; private set; } 
    public Window1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      basicUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>();
      basicUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe" });
      basicUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe" });

      customUsers = new CustomTypeUsers();
      customUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "Natasha Doe" });
      customUsers.Add(new User() { Name = "Angelina Doe" });

       DataContext = this;
   }
}

public class User
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomTypeUsers : ObservableCollection<User>
{
    public CustomTypeUsers()
    {

        Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe" });
        Add(new User() { Name = "Betty Doe" });
    }
}
}
```

in XAML :

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<Window.Resources>
    <!-- source=DataContext is already set in code behind to object where collections are defined = MainWindow = this -->
    <!--    if defined in other classes use for example :   <csrc:CustomTypeUsers  x:Key="refSource"/> -->

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="lbUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding basicUsers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="10,10,70,141" Width="212"></ListBox>
    <ListBox Name="lbUsers2" ItemsSource="{Binding customUsers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="10,149,70,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=customUsers.[2].Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="196,128,0,116"/>
</Grid>
```